# behaviour of qunit throws with various other imports

Tags: javascript, qunit

I wanted to do a simple test to see if i got the workings of throws. So i made an example for myself, but it crashes and i do not know why.

```
asyncTest('Testing submission system', function(){

    ... // Decaration of the mockCreators

    throws(function(){ // Text book example
        throw 'error'
    }, 'throws an error')
    mainView.registerSave(mockCreator);
    mainView.registerSave(mockCreator2);
    mainView.registerSave(mockCreator3);
    mainView.registerSave(mockCreator4);
    throws(mainView.registerSave(mockCreator2), 'also throws an error')
    mainView.startParsing();
});
```

My actual `mainView.registerSave` :

```
registerSave: function(object)
    {
        if(typeof(object.model) === 'undefined')throw 'Crash: Missing "model" attribute'
        if(typeof(object.parseData) !== 'function')throw 'Crash: Missing "parseData" function'
        if(typeof(object.saveData) !=='function')throw 'Crash: Missing "saveData" function'
        if(_.indexOf(this.subscribed, object) !== -1)throw 'Save already registered'
        this.subscribed.push(object);
    },
```

`mainView` is extended from `Backbone.views`

The crash:

```
Died on test #2     at QUnit.asyncTest (http://localhost:8080/JSLib/qunit-1.14.0.js:108:9)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/CreateStory/testCreateStory.js:292:2)
at fire (http://localhost:8080/JSLib/jquery-1.11.1.js:3119:30)
at Object.self.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:8080/JSLib/jquery-1.11.1.js:3231:7)
at Function.jQuery.extend.ready (http://localhost:8080/JSLib/jquery-1.11.1.js:3443:13)
at HTMLDocument.completed (http://localhost:8080/JSLib/jquery-1.11.1.js:3474:10): Save already registered
```

And further more i use these libaries:

- jquery-1.11.1
- underscore-min (latest)
- backbone (latest)
- bootstrap 3
- sinon 1.10.2
- qunit 1.14.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of throws has to be a callback, not the method-call itself, try this:

```
throws(function() { mainView.registerSave(mockCreator2);}, 'also throws an error')
```